# Passport.js LocalStrategy returns 401 despite successful deserialization

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've read a lot of similar topics but did not found anything like mine. Here is what I see in console:

```
85.114.2.255 - - [Thu, 10 Apr 2014 11:46:36 GMT] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Local Authentication
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM `phpfox_user` WHERE `phpfox_user`.`email`='zelibobla@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SUCCESS
************************** SERIALIZING 13051
85.114.2.255 - - [Thu, 10 Apr 2014 11:46:37 GMT] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> DESERIALIZING 13051
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM `phpfox_user` WHERE `phpfox_user`.`user_id`=13051 LIMIT 1;
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DESERIALIZED: zelibobla@gmail.com
[Function]
85.114.2.255 - - [Thu, 10 Apr 2014 11:46:37 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401
```

There is a bit interference, but we can see here that login form request is successfull. Smubmitted form accepted and triggered database search for user. User found and serialized into session. After that redirection to '/' route followed. At this route user deserialization performed and (surprise!) HTTP_401 returned.
I spend 2 days trying to figure out why I get such a strange behavior. Any help is appeciated.

Here is a simplified code representing my app.

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var path = require( 'path' );
var passport = require( 'passport' );

core = express();

core.passport = require( 'passport' );
var LocalStrategy = require( 'passport-local' ).Strategy;

core.passport.use( 'local', new LocalStrategy(
    function( email, password, done ){
console.log( '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Local Authentication' );
        core.factories.user.find({ where: {
                email: email,
            }})
            .success( function( user ){
                if( null === user ){
                    return done( /* errorText = */ null,
                                 false,
                                 { message: 'User with specified email not found' }
                            );
                }
                var authService = core.services.authentication()
                    hash = user.password,
                    salt = user.password_salt;
                if( authService.isPasswordValid( password, hash, salt ) ){
console.log( "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SUCCESS" );
                    return done( /* errorText = */ null, user );
                } else {
console.log( "<<< !!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR" );
                    return done( /* errorText = */ null, false, { message: 'Password invalid' });
                }
            })
            .error( function( errorText ){
                return done( errorText );
            });
    })
);

core.passport.serializeUser( function( user, done ){
console.log( '************************** SERIALIZING ' + user.user_id );
    done( /* errorText = */ null, user.user_id );
});

core.passport.deserializeUser( function( id, done ){
console.log( '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> DESERIALIZING ' + id );
    core.factories.user.find( id )
        .success( function( user ){
console.log( '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DESERIALIZED: ' + user.email );
console.log( done );
            done( /* errorText = */ null, user );
        })
        .error( function( errorText ){
console.log( '<<<< !!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< error\n' + errorText );
            done( errorText );
        });
});

core.use( express.cookieParser() );
core.use( express.bodyParser() );
core.use( express.session({ secret: "GodBlessJaredHanson" }) );
core.use( passport.initialize() );
core.use( passport.session() );
core.use( express.methodOverride() );
core.use( core.router );
core.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'public' ) ) );
core.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExeptions: true, showStack: true }) );

core.set( 'views', __dirname + '/public' );
core.engine( 'html', require( 'ejs' ).renderFile );

core.get( '/', [
    core.passport.authenticate( 'local' ),
    function( request, response ){
console.log( "****************** GOOD! I am rendering index.html ********************" );
        return response.render( 'index.html' );
    },
] );
core.get( '/login', function( request, response ){
    response.render( 'login.html', {errors:{}, email: ''} );
}, );
core.post( '/login', core.passport.authenticate( 'local', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' } ) );


var instance = core.listen( '1339' );
module.exports = instance;
```

**UPDATE:**

Well, example of library author helped. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

Instead of

```
core.get( '/', [
    core.passport.authenticate( 'local' ),
    function( request, response ){
console.log( "****************** GOOD! I am rendering index.html ********************" );
        return response.render( 'index.html' );
    },
] );
```

Access control should be performed this way:

```
core.get( '/', [
    function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
},
    function( request, response ){
console.log( "****************** GOOD! I am rendering index.html ********************" );
        return response.render( 'index.html' );
    },
] );
```

The key of misundestanding was that other strategies like BearerStrategy are used to run authentification process on every new request.

Comment: Why did you call `passport.authenticate()` in the route handler for `GET /`? Just try `core.get('/', function(request, response){response.render('index.html');})`.

Comment: @bnuhero maybe I need passport to perform authorized access to this page?